# Remove functionality on element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to come with a way to remove functionality on a tag. I'm used to jquery and the code would be something like this.

```
$(document).on("click",".goto-messages:not(done)", function(e){...
...$(".profile-messages").addClass("done");
```

I'm trying to achieve the same thing using javascript but I'm failing at adding class attribut. I'm also not sure how to add the argument to not fire a function e.g. ":not(done)"

```
            document.getElementsByTagName("td").onclick = function(){
                this.style.background = blue;
                this.class
            }
```

How do I achieve this result in javascript?
I want to remove the functionality of the element that is clicked.

Also is the line "this.style.background = blue;" correct?

Comment: What functionality do you want to remove?

Comment: What's wrong with using jQuery? Event delegation is complicated to implement when you care about cross-browser-compatibility.

Comment: don't you mean `".goto-messages:not(.done)"` with a dot before the `done` class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want something like this (unless you provide some HTML), example uses [element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList) which is not supported by all browsers. But you can use something like [domtokenlist library](http://code.google.com/p/domtokenlist/) which should give you good support across all browsers, or there are some RegEx's that can be found in [Adding and Removing Classes, with simple cross-browser JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript/196038#196038). As for adding events cross browser, instead of using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), you can take a look at the following [How to make this Javascript function work in IE Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17150461/592253) or do a search on SO for [`addEvent`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20addEvent).

HTML

```
<table>
    <theader>
        <tr>
            <th>Mesages A</th>
            <th>Mesages B</th>
        </tr>
    </theader>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="profile-messages">Message1</td>
            <td class="profile-messages">Message2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="profile-messages">Message3</td>
            <td class="profile-messages">Message4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="profile-messages">Message5</td>
            <td class="profile-messages">Message6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.profile-messages {
    background-color: red;
}
.done {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Javascript

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "TD" && evt.target.classList.contains("profile-messages")) {
        evt.target.classList.add("done");
    }
}, false);
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/5xQbb/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

[`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), you have to iterate it:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i=0, len = nodes.length; i<len; i++) {
  nodes.item(i).onclick = function () {
    // do something
  };
}
```

Use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) for a CSS-like selector:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".goto-messages:not(.done)");
```